# Is the 하소서체 speech level used in any modern setting?

Tags: speech-levels

Would I ever hear 하소서체 language used naturally in any modern setting, or is it just something that was used historically for talking to royalty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still used a lot in church when praying to God, like this:

> 주님 우리를 인도하여 주옵소서!  (Please lead us, Lord)

I'm not sure if it's used in Buddhist prayers or not.

And of course we can hear it a lot in historical dramas, so it remains familiar to people even if they never use it.